# url redirection after url rewriting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The actual URL structure is:

```
www.domain.com/browse-string.html
```

The new URL will be:

```
www.domain.com/browse-magazines-string.html
```

Basically we are adding magazines to the string, if it was just a single page, we could use:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.domain.com/browse-string.html http://www.domain.com/browse-magazines-string.html
```

But we have hundreds of pages and can not figure out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(browse)-([^.-]+\.html)$ /$1-magazines-$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but does not work, if clicking the old url it redirects to the index page and not to the page it should...any idea why?

Comment: It did work in my testing. Do you have any other rule in your .htaccess? If yes post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: yes its a longgggg .htaccess

Comment: it doesnt allow me to post it here because it is too long...

Comment: OMG, try placing above rule right on top just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: I have tried placing at top and at different other places and nothing old url is redirected to the index page...

Comment: Can you try in a different browser. Hope you're still trying `www.domain.com/browse-string.html` URL and there is no CMS/PHP framework running here?

Comment: nothing, have tried different browser, computer but redirection goes to index